# Reactjs and Nodejs Comunication in vs code

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am very new to React and node js. I have created one "Hello World" project in reactjs. It is working fine.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Helllloooooooo</div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';


// var Books = require('./apicall.js');

// var books = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('initial-data').getAttribute('data-json'));  
// ReactDOM.render(<Books books={books} />, document.getElementById('root')); 

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tag above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

i have created a new js file in src folder in node js for api call,

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var client = new Client();
client.registerMethod("jsonMethod", "http://webapi.com/Service.svc/xyz/value/1?format=json", "GET");

client.methods.jsonMethod(function (data, response) {
    // parsed response body as js object 
    console.log(data);
    // raw response 


});
```

how i can call this node api to react so that i can see the response in json format. Please help!!

Comment: This should be done over http, with something called an ajax call. Google this and you will find all the info you need.

Comment: Basically ajax means, that the browser does another request to the server without loading a new page (this can be done in JavaScript inside the browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can see this demo .

[github link](https://github.com/react-redux-mvvm/react-redux-mvvm)

run with : npm run dev

Comment: tried but it is not working. is redux plugin for React?

Comment: Yes, react+redux.But you can send ajax request from frontend side .